# Do I need to replace clutch kit when refitting engine

Tags: maintenance, clutch, renault

My car engine was stripped by Renault under warranty and fixed, now they want me to pay for replacing the clutch as they feel it will go soon. My question is aren't they supposed to replace the clutch kit as well when fitting the engine back to the car. Isn't that a rule that once you remove the gearbox from the engine when fitting everything back you need to replace all clutch kit components.

Am not a mechanic and feel they are ripping me off, please help.

Comment: Wouldn't be in the US. If you don't want them to replace the clutch, tell them to put the old one back in. If I were you, I'd have them a new one on anyway, as proper maintenance. There shouldn't be any *extra labor* involved, but parts would be on the owner. The reason for no extra labor is because they have to put it back on as part of refitting the engine. A clutch kit now will save you a *lot* in labor if you take care of it now instead of when it goes out in the future. JMHO, though.

Comment: Agree, unless they are charging you a lot more labor.  They are probably trying to save you money.

Comment: Clutches are considered to be similar to break pads by almost all the manufacturers.  They are a consumable and need to be replaced from time to time.  I wouldn't feel like they were ripping me off at all.  It's just the way that it is.

Comment: It is ok if they only charge you for parts and not labor. If the engine is out to be rebuilt they would have removed the clutch anyway and they can install the new parts without additional labor.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up, just that I do not totally trust the delears they can be dodgy at time.

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't a rule and usually isn't done if not required. However, if an engine is removed because it needs to be rebuilt, it's usually the case that the clutch is worn enough to make it beneficial to do at the same time. Replacing the clutch when the engine is already out is usually pretty trivial, so it makes sense to do it at that time if the clutch has significant wear. It shouldn't cost you much more than a couple hours of labor plus parts.

How many miles/kms are on your clutch? If the engine is being replaced under warranty that suggests that it doesn't have many miles/kms on it. If it's over 50K miles/80K kilometers then it's probably a good idea to go ahead and get it done.

Comment: car has 98600km and I'm not sure if the clutch was changed before as I bought as used car. Thank you again, will ask the dealer to replace it just for peace of mind.